# Graylog2 with Symfony 2 (Monolog)

Tags: php, symfony, monolog, graylog2

I want to use the "Monolog -> GelfHandler" in a SF2 project. So I've added the following to my composer.json:

```
"graylog2/gelf-php": "dev-master"
```

My SF2 config.yml:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: gelf
            publisher:
                hostname: %Graylog2.Host%
                port: %Graylog2.Port%
            level: info
            formatter: monolog.formatter.session_request
```

But now, if I want to log something, I get an error in GelfHandler::write()

```
Gelf\Publisher::publish() must be an instance of Gelf\MessageInterface, string given
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: What's your specific symfony version? Or better yet, can you paste the output you get from `composer show --installed`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ok, i will answer my question by my self. the failure is to change the "formatter" or you have to use a formatter is sub-classes from *Monolog\Formatter\GelfMessageFormatter*.

thx @ all

Comment: Hi, that's great! Maybe you could also add the final configuration with everything in place? Thanks!