# to send logs from php application to graylog using monolog

Tags: php, logging, monolog, graylog

I have installed graylog server and its dependencies.Trying to send logs from my php application to graylog server using Monolog.
But I am not aware of how to use the Gelf handler.I have seen the GelfHandlerTest.php that is present inside the project Monolog but I am not able to set my publisher and create the handler.Can please anybody explain me with a sample code how to use it.

Trying to send logs from my localhost apache to a server that is set up in the same private network where the graylog is installed.

The testLogging file that is getting executed in PHP are,

```
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\GelfHandler;
use Gelf\Message;
use Monolog\Formatter\GelfMessageFormatter;


$handler = new GelfHandler($publisher);
```

How to set the publisher in monolog?

Any sort of help is appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3):

Please check the following links:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-logging-to-graylog2

[Graylog2 with Symfony 2 (Monolog)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764876/graylog2-with-symfony-2-monolog)

Basically you need something like:
`$handler = new GelfHandler(new Gelf\Publisher(`
`new Gelf\Transport\TcpTransport(HOST,PORT)`
`));`

The transport must be the input you added in the grayog platform.Ex:
`new TcpTransport(127.0.0.1,12201)`

Available transports:
https://github.com/bzikarsky/gelf-php/tree/master/src/Gelf/Transport

Hope it helps.